# How to achieve Document formatting track changes with aspose using openxml

Tags: cpu-word, aspose

I am using Aspose library. Since **Aspose doesn't support Document formatting track changes** is there any way to achieve this?
I need to use Aspose but need to achieve document formatting track changes. can we add openxml after all operations completed to achieve this or can we set document start revisions using openxml and use aspose for changes?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are right, Aspose.Words does not support tracking formatting changes. There are plans to add this feature (WORDSNET-15792) in one of future versions of Aspose.Words.
I would advice you to make a request of this feature in [Aspose.Words forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8) to get an automatic notification once this feature is available.

Disclosure: I work at Aspose.Words team.